# Compatible almost complex structures such that the associated riemannian metric has positive injectivity radius

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, differential-topology, sg.symplectic-geometry

Let $M$ be a compact manifold, consider $\omega$ the canonical symplectic form in $T^*M$ and $\hat J$ the canonical almost complex structure coming from the Sasaki metric.

Let $\mathcal{J}$ be the set all $t$-dependent $1$-periodic smooth $\omega-$compatible almost complex structures on $T^*M$ such that $||J-\hat J||<\infty$. One can put a distance on $\mathcal{J}$ defined as $\text{dist}(J_1,J_2)=||J_1-J_2||_{\infty}+dist_{C^{\infty}_{loc}}(J_1,J_2)$, so that it's a complete metric space.
Now I was wondering what can be said about the set $J_t\in \mathcal{J}$ such that $g_t:=\omega(.,J_t)$ has positive injectivity radius ? Can anything be said about this set ? In particular would we have that this set is dense ?

Any insight is appreciated, thanks in advance.